# javascript beginner- how to obtain class for a div or other html node

Tags: javascript

In a web page there is a div with a value specified for its class.

Now, I have with me the node corresponding to the div, how do I obtain the class of that div, using the node (which is stored in a js variable)?

Example--

```
<div class="test" id="div1">
Some random text
</div>
```

How do I obtain the class value (i.e. "test")  when I have with me the node that represents the above div?

Comment: Why don't you provide your actual code? And it sounds like `el.className` property is what you're after.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: @Amit - Why? You don't need jQuery simply to get a node's `className` property value.

Comment: @JaredFarrish http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: document.getElementById("div1").className; or jquery equivalent $('#div1').attr('class');

Comment: @Nicosunshine - Bobince is a funny dude (dudette?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');

console.log(div1.className);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XWqu8/

Prints in the Javascript console:

```
test
```

Note as well that a `class` value can represent multiple classes, e.g.:

```
<div class="test other oneMore" id="div1">
Some random text
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XWqu8/

Which prints:

```
test other oneMore
```